# Почему второй вызов RasGetEntryProperties() возвращает Overlapped I/O operation is in progress?

Tags: c, winapi

Есть такой код:

```
#include <ras.h>
#include <raserror.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DWORD dwEntryInfoSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDeviceInfoSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    LPRASENTRY lpRasEntry = NULL;
    LPBYTE lpDeviceInfo = NULL;

    /**
     * Create RAS connection
     *
     * Get buffer sizing information for a default phonebook entry
     */
    if ((dwRet = RasGetEntryProperties(NULL, "", NULL, &dwEntryInfoSize, NULL, &dwDeviceInfoSize)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        if (dwRet != ERROR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) {
            printf("RasGetEntryProperties error: %s\n", GetLastError());

            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (dwEntryInfoSize == 0) {
        printf("Entry info size error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    lpRasEntry = (LPRASENTRY) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwEntryInfoSize);

    if (lpRasEntry == NULL) {
        printf("HeapAlloc RasEntry error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (dwDeviceInfoSize) {
        lpDeviceInfo = (LPBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwDeviceInfoSize);
    }

    lpRasEntry->dwSize = sizeof(RASENTRY);

    // Вот здесь возникает ошибка: Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.
    // Кстати, ошибка возникает в Windows XP а в Windows 10 все работает
    // прекрасно. Мне нужно чтобы этот код работал именно в XP
    if ((dwRet = RasGetEntryProperties(NULL, "", lpRasEntry, &dwEntryInfoSize, lpDeviceInfo, &dwDeviceInfoSize)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("RasGetEntryProperties error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Validate new phonebook name "TestEntry"
    if ((dwRet = RasValidateEntryName(NULL, "TestEntry")) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("RasValidateEntryName error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Install a new phonebook entry, "TestEntry", using default properties
    if ((dwRet = RasSetEntryProperties(NULL, "TestEntry", lpRasEntry, dwEntryInfoSize, lpDeviceInfo, dwDeviceInfoSize)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("RasSetEntryProperties error: %s\n", GetLastError());

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Deallocate memory for the connection buffer
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, lpRasEntry);
    lpRasEntry = NULL;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Этот код создает обычное модемное соединение (dial-up). И я застрял на этом баге.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде обнаружились ошибки...

Ошибка #1: Функции Ras* не устанавливают коды ошибок для GetLastError(). Т.е. GetLastError() не имеет смысла. Они возвращают коды ошибок как DWORD. Читайте Routing and Remote Access Error Codes в MSDN.

Ошибка #2: Начиная с NT в функции RasGetEntryProperties() 5 и 6 параметры не используются и должны быть равны NULL.

Ошибка #3: Самая коварная. Дело в том что размеры структуры RASENTRY для некоторых ОС Windows различаются. Например, между XP и 10. Поэтому где нибудь в заголовочных файлах мы должны указывать что то вроде этого:

```
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
```

Подробнее можно почитать в MSDN. Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT. В данном случае мы указали версию Windows XP. То что мне и было нужно. А Overlapped I/O operation is in progress вообще никакого отношения к нам не имеет в данном случае. Мы просто вывели результат GetLastError() который наверное возник где нибудь в недрах Windows при выполнений предыдущих функции.